# How to combine MKV video and separate audio?

Tags: windows-10, audio, video, matroska, combine

I have `MKV` video and separate audio in `.ac3` format. MKV file has its own embedded audio records, but I don’t need them. I need to unify video from `MKV` file and my separate audio of `.ac3` format.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Use `mkvmerge` from [mkvtoolnix](https://mkvtoolnix.download/), works on Linux and Windows. (Add an OS tag if you use a different OS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use mkvmerge from [mkvtoolnix](https://mkvtoolnix.download/), works on Linux and Windows.